# Exchange Online Group Calendar entries are not replicated to all members

Tags: calendar, exchangeonline, office365

I created a group in Exchange Online (Microsoft 365 group type) and added a few test members. The target is to have a shared calendar. "Subscribe new members" checkmark is enabled.
All test users can regularly see the new group calendar in their Outlook, under "All group calendars" but when I add new events to the group calendar on my Outlook, other users don't see anything.

I'm aware that I could even create a new group directly in Outlook and invite other members. In this manner everything works fine.

At the same time I don't understand why the first method does not work as desired. What is the sense of making the calendar available to all users if it is not replicated?

Comment: As far as I can see, when I create a new group/calendar directly from Outlook, a new SharePoint site is created. If create a group in Exchange Online, no SPO sites are created and I assume that the calendar is managed by Exchange itself.

Comment: Any updates on your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I get back on the shared mailbox I set up that time and now it simply working as expected... what to say??

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same test (your first method) in my lab, I add a new event in the Microsoft 365 group calendar and the group member can see the event.

To narrow down this issue and determine whether this issue occurs to exchange side or outlook side, Could you add the event in OWA and check if this issue continues?